# Consulta SQL limit 10

Tags: mysql, sql

Alguien me podría ayudar a realizar una consulta que muestre por cada categoría 10 registros¿??. Es decir si tengo las categorías: 
coches, motos, barcos.

Pues de cada una necesito 10 registros.

De momento estoy intentando con limit, pero no lo consigo, ya que me muestra solo 10 registros pero de todas las categorías y necesito 10 por cada una.

```
SELECT fc.titulo_categoria, f.titulo, f.url
FROM sne_formacion_categoria as fc, sne_formacion_categoria_area as fca, sne_formacion f, 
 sne_candidato_areas as ca
WHERE fca.id_formacion_categoria = fc.id_categoria
AND fc.id_categoria = f.id_categoria
AND ca.id_area = fca.id_area
AND ca.id_candidato = 64
order by rand()
limit 0,10
```

Comment: Podrías añadir en tu where un and de una de las categorías, con el límite 10, y una vez hecho eso una UNION de varias select cambiando la categoría. Como tal no es muy optimo, además que deberías hacer inner joins con esas tablas en lugar de producto cartesiano.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No habría una solución mejor¿?